# cocoapods framework much slower in my app than in example

Tags: ios, 32bit-64bit

I don't think that it's specific to that framework, but with [TOMSMorphingLabel](https://github.com/tomknig/TOMSMorphingLabel) it's very obvious: I saw that the animations are very slow on my iPhone 5 (no problems on my iPhone 7+) and then I tried out the example from the website: those animations ran smoothly as expected.

What could be the reason for this? There are no other operations running in the background, may that have to do something with Build Settings, the 32bit architecture or something like that?

Comment: I don't think it may have any concern with the architecture.

Comment: maybe post your code will helps...

Comment: I believe that without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it would be very hard to get useful response. My first bet would be that some other part of your app doing some heavy task on the UI thread or other threads and thus interferes with animations. Have you tried to profile your app for CPU load?

Answer (score 3):

`TOMSMorphingLabel` is working at expected speed in my `iPhone5s` , `iPhone6` & `iPhone7` even in simulator of `iPhone5`. I don't find any issue with the framework.

The speed may be slow due to low memory on your device or low processing capacity. Please try testing it in 5s. See if the problem is reproduced or not. If the speed gets slow in lower end devices like iPhone 5 then definitely the processor and memory of the device are at fault.

Answer (score 0):

you can also have a look at LTMorphingLabel which may be more performant.

[LTMorphingLabel](https://github.com/lexrus/LTMorphingLabel)

more performance than the other. :)